# AUDIT TABLE AND SESSIONS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a few questions or queries.
1. I want to select entries which are entered in the current session if there is any.

example .

```
insert into tablename (columns)
values (values)
```

then select the entries entered since logon.

I have tried using the sysprocesses but it gives me everything entered by the user but includes many sessions so I want only the current session
1. I have a table and its audit table.

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('tbl_sessions_shadow','U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE tbl_sessions_shadow
GO


CREATE TABLE tbl_sessions_shadow
(
[RecID] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
Ptid CHAR(9)NOT NULL,
Session_Code VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL ,
Schedule_Date DATE NOT NULL,
FinalOutcome VARCHAR(25),
entered_by VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT (system_user),
date_entered DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
edited_by VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT (system_user),
edit_date DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
edit_reason VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (PTID,SESSION_CODE,SCHEDULE_dATE,EDIT_REASON),
--CHECK ( LEN(edit_reason)> 2),
CHECK (LEN(PTID)=9)

)
```

on my front end I have an option for edit reasons which are initial entry and correction.
the requirement is that it should take "correction" the first time I edit a record and should not allow "initial entry" for 2nd ,3rd,.....edits for 'edit reason' column.
I have tried this :

```
IF (SELECT * 
FROM TBL_SESSIONS_SHADOW 
WHERE PTID=@PTID AND SESSION_CODE=@SESSION_cODE) IS NULL AND @EDIT_REASON = 'CORRECTION'
BEGIN 
RAISERROR('ERROR',16,1)
GOTO ABORT
END
```

Comment: where's your question? Please read [ask].

Comment: thanks I will bear that in mind